# Keras Connected Convolutional Layers: Data Format Needed on Every Conv Layer

Tags: keras, conv-neural-network

Using connected, successive `Conv2D` layers in Keras, do I need to set the `data_format` on every layer, or just the first?  My data are in NCHW (channels-first) format.

To provide some context, I have a Keras network that consists of multiple connected `Conv2D` layers in succession.  My images are:

- grayscale;
- 84x84 pixels;
- stacks of 4 so that each sample has an indication of velocity (i.e. a sample consists of 4 sequenced images, and I train on batches of these samples).

In other words, each sample is of the shape `(4, 84, 84)`.  Here is my model, which is a Deep-q Network implementation:

```python
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

'''
 ' Huber loss: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Huber_loss
'''
def huber_loss(y_true, y_pred):
  error = y_true - y_pred
  cond  = tf.keras.backend.abs(error) < 1.0

  squared_loss = 0.5 * tf.keras.backend.square(error)
  linear_loss  = tf.keras.backend.abs(error) - 0.5

  return tf.where(cond, squared_loss, linear_loss)

'''
 ' Importance Sampling weighted huber loss.
'''
def huber_loss_mean_weighted(y_true, y_pred, is_weights):
  error = huber_loss(y_true, y_pred)

  return tf.keras.backend.mean(error * is_weights)


# The observation input.
in_obs = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(4, 84, 84))

# The importance sampling weights are used with the custom loss function,
# and correct for the non-uniform distribution of the samples.
in_is_weights = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(1,))

# Expectations when training (the output is qualities for actions).
in_actual = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(4,))

# Normalize the observation to the range of [0, 1].
norm = tf.keras.layers.Lambda(lambda x: x / 255.0)(in_obs)

# Convolutional layers per the Nature paper on DQN.
conv1 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=32, kernel_size=8, strides=4,
  activation="relu", data_format="channels_first")(norm)
conv2 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=64, kernel_size=4, strides=2,
  activation="relu", data_format="channels_first")(conv1)
conv3 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=64, kernel_size=3, strides=1,
  activation="relu", data_format="channels_first")(conv2)

# Flatten, and move to the fully-connected part of the network.
flatten = tf.keras.layers.Flatten()(conv3)
dense1  = tf.keras.layers.Dense(512, activation="relu")(flatten)

# Output prediction.
out_pred = tf.keras.layers.Dense(4, activation="linear")(dense1)

# Using Adam optimizer, RMSProp's successor.
opt = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(lr=5e-5, decay=0.0)

# This network is used for training.
train_network = tf.keras.models.Model(
  inputs=[in_obs, in_actual, in_is_weights],
  outputs=out_pred)

# The custom loss, which is Huber Loss weighted by IS weights.
train_network.add_loss(
  huber_loss_mean_weighted(out_pred, in_actual, in_is_weights))

train_network.compile(optimizer=opt, loss=None)
```

Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need it in every layer, or you can set it in your keras config file:

- Linux: `~/.keras/keras.json`
- Windows: `C:\users\<yourusername>\.keras\keras.json`

But honestly, you should better swap the axes from your data, as other keras functions tend to work always on the last axis. So, having channels at the last axis may save you a lot of additional work.

To change your data:

```
np.moveaxis(data,1,-1)
```

Comment: Thank you.  I thought about rolling the axis (actually per one of your answers to someone else's question!), but in the case of the code I'm currently working on doing so adds complexity elsewhere.  Anyway, thanks again for the help.

Comment: @Danial Möller, I have a difficulty in displaying an image once its axis are swapped, since the dimension would become `(84,4)` for a single image. Do I need to swap back to the original format to display an image?

Comment: @iamkk, as far as I know, the most common libraries that display images use channels last. They take (x, y, 4) as input shape, just as the Keras standard.